# CMD: Popupmessage IF file created < 5 minutes AND file > 1 MB

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want a pop up notification when a .GEO file comes into a folder that was created 5 minutes ago (or less) AND is larger than 1 MB.

> ```
> Folder: T:\Klanten
> ```

This is what I've found so far:

I run a CMD every 5 minutes that checks if there is a file larger than 1MB.
If he found one, it will run another CMD:

```
forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize GEQ 1048576 start test2.cmd"
```

The second CMD gives the pop up message:

```
echo calling popup
START /WAIT CMD /C "ECHO File in Watch CADMAN too big && ECHO. && PAUSE"
echo we are back!
```

I need to build a function in the first CMD where it checks if the file larger than 1 MB was created 5 minutes ago or less.

If someone can send a working CMD code that would be great!

Comment: Why do you run a `.cmd` script to run a `.cmd` script? Anyway, `start /WAIT cmd /C "…"` should read `start "" /WAIT cmd /C "…"`…

Comment: Simply because I didn't know how to combine these 2 .cmd to 1 .cmd. But i don't know how your answer helps with my problem?

Comment: Alright; you could perhaps just use this: `forfiles /S /C "cmd /D /C if @fsize geq 1048576 start 0x220x22 /WAIT cmd /D /C 0x22echo File too big!& echo/& pause0x22"` (I don't know if you actually need the `/WAIT` option though; note that files must be less than 2 GiB in size to succeed). Anyway, my suggestion was not meant to be the solution, but it prevents `start` from taking the first quoted string as a window title rather than a command…

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "monitor=%sourcedir%\monitor.txt"

:: list files larger than required

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.geo" 2^>nul'
 ) DO IF %%~zb gtr 10 ECHO "%%b"
)>"%monitor%.new"

:: Compare list against previous list (if any)

IF EXIST "%monitor%" FC "%monitor%" "%monitor%.new" >NUL 2>nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO START "GEO monitor report" ...whatever...

:: replace monitor list

MOVE /y "%monitor%.new" "%monitor%" >nul


GOTO :eof
```

The `for` locates files in the required directory and subdirectories (`/s`) in basic form `/b` (ie. filename-only) and reports any that have a size (`%~zb`) greater than - I used `10` for testing. The filenames are gathered into the `...new` file and are quoted. The `2>nul` suppresses error messages from `dir` - the `^` is required to tell `cmd` that the `>` is part of the `dir` command, not of the `for`.

See `for /?` from the prompt to learn about metavariable modifiers.

Then compare against the previous list, suppressing reports from `fc`.

`fc` will set `errorlevel` to zero if the  files are the same, so detect that the files are not the same, and generate your pop-up.

Then replace the previous monitor file with the new version.

Of course, the monitor files may be placed anywhere - I just used the source directory for my convenience.

Comment: This is what I get:
- %%b was unexpected at this time.
- ''dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
- The system cannot find the specified file.

Comment: He always does the popup message. Something goes wrong checking if the monitor.txt file has been changed or not.